# UIImageView.image not loading

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I have a strange issue with loading an imageview into a UITableViewCell during:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

here is my code:

```
    UIImageView *title = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,10,300,150)] autorelease];

    title.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"featured_graphic.png" ];
    title.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    title.alpha = 1.0;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

its inside this:

```
 if( [indexPath isEqual:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] )
 {
 }
```

I verified that featured_graphic.png is in my application.

Comment: More details: Did you try to put it outside of the if statement? What is happening? Did you set the row height appropriately?

Comment: @CodeBrickie it was appearing before.. now its not showing up

Comment: @dasdom Yes, row height is set correctly. I even stepped through it and it goes into the If Statement and executes fine.

Comment: I don't see the code where you added the `UIImageView` called `title` to the cell. Perhaps the problem lies there.

Comment: duh!!! Thanks to everyone for their assistance. That was a dumb mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the title but you don't actually add it to the view.

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:title];
```